# Composer query to match a participant reference

Tags: hyperledger-composer

So I have a query like this:

```
query selectOrder{
  description: "Select an Order that matches a Client reference and an Order Number"
  statement:
      SELECT com.x.Order
      WHERE (client == _$client AND orderNumber == _$orderNumber)
}
```

The order is something like this:

```
asset Order identified by uuid {
  o String uuid
  --> Client client
  o String orderNumber
  --> Item[] items 
}
```

How do I pass the reference to the client to the query?

I tried the reference and was told to toJSON it.
I tried that and it won't parse the thing - there's a clear issue with the parsing of the query.

I can't find the answer in the docs, so I'm wondering if anyone has done this or if I have to save the client id instead of the reference to client and lose the integrity.

**EDIT:** For completeness for the first answer below.

I'm trying to add an Item to the array of Items.
My Item object is defined like this:

```
asset Item identified by uuid {
  o String uuid
  o DateTime timestamp
  o String orderNumber  
  --> Client client
  o String[] message
}
```

When the transaction is invoked the single object passed in is the Item.
I'm setting Item.client as the _$client value in the query.

Should I be pre-pending it with "resource:"? 
I'm asking because I thought that was in the reference string already - at least it is in the view in the playground.

**EDIT2:**
So I manually construct the following variable:

```
var RSRC = 'resource:com.x.Client#XYZ123'
```

Set that as the client in this query

```
return query('selectOrder', {agency : RSRC, orderNumber : orderNumber});
```

But I'm still getting this:

> Error: unknown operator "0" - should be one of $eq, $lte, $lt, $gt,
>   $gte, $exists, $ne, $in, $nin, $size, $mod, $regex, $elemMatch, $type
>   or $all

What next? 
Embedding the "resource..." string in quotes didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks ok, but you need to pass a string with the format:
`resource:type.Name#instance` for the relationship.

E.g. `resource:org.acme.Car#123ABC`

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more verbose. I'll edit the original to show where the _$client is coming from.